# WP10 Detected Bluetooth device functions

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, uwp

As all users of Windows Phone 10 know, the Bluetooth connectivity on this system is cutted to the simplest for end-user, which ends for programmers as a horror to create anything. 
When connecting to a device, system automatically looks for a "functions" that device has, for ex. audio. 
The questions are as following:
1. How to define a function like that on external Android device? The main goal is, to control all types of music playback from it (ex. Groove music playing)
2. Where can i find a list of things like this, for future app functions?

And to get ahead of answers, I already tried the easier ways, which came to nothing due to UWP limits of controlling other apps playback.

Main target of project is to make a xamarin c# (or java, I can "translate" from one to another with ease) android app for a smartwatch and in c# uwp for windows phone to do most common tasks, like - as mentioned before - music playback control and notifications reciever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, you want to develop an Android app to send Bluetooth command to control the music player of a windows phone device, then it depends on your Bluetooth of your android device.

But control music player by Bluetooth need the profile `Avrcp` I have check the google [Bluetooth API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothProfile.html) I did not find the profile of  `Avrcp`, I think it is may be hard to send the `Avrcp` command at the android application level.

And Android is source opened, many device factories prefer to customize their own Android system, it is possible that the device uses a Bluetooth module as a serial device, then the official Bluetooth APIs are not suitable for this scenario, the develop protocol of this Bluetooth module is in need.